# Fudan FM33LG048 microcontroller draws too much current in deep sleep mode

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, low-power

I am working with Fudan FM33LG048 low power microcontrollers. Despite turning off all clocks except low frequency external oscillator, disabling all peripherals, and entering to the deep sleep mode the MCU still draws 63uA. The datasheet (available only in Chineese unfortunately) says that in deep sleep mode it must draw only 2uA.

Has anyone worked with these microcontrollers and if yes anyone knows what can the reason be?

**EDIT:**

```c
void DeepSleep(void)
{
        FL_PMU_SleepInitTypeDef LPM_InitStruct;
        
        FL_RMU_PDR_Enable(RMU);                         // ??PDR
        FL_RMU_BOR_Disable(RMU);                    // ??BOR 2uA
        FL_GPIO_ALLPIN_LPM_MODE();

        FL_CMU_SetSystemClockSource(FL_CMU_SYSTEM_CLK_SOURCE_XTLF);

        //FL_CMU_SetSystemClockSource(FL_CMU_SYSTEM_CLK_SOURCE_RCLF);
        //FL_CMU_RCLF_Disable();
        FL_CMU_RCHF_Disable();
        FL_CMU_XTHF_Disable();

        FL_VREF_Disable(VREF);              // ??VREF1p2

        LPM_InitStruct.deepSleep            = FL_PMU_SLEEP_MODE_DEEP;
        LPM_InitStruct.powerMode            = 
        FL_PMU_POWER_MODE_SLEEP_OR_DEEPSLEEP;
        LPM_InitStruct.wakeupFrequency      = FL_PMU_RCHF_WAKEUP_FREQ_8MHZ;
        LPM_InitStruct.wakeupDelay          = FL_PMU_WAKEUP_DELAY_2US;
        LPM_InitStruct.LDOLowPowerMode      = FL_PMU_LDO_LPM_ENABLE;
        LPM_InitStruct.coreVoltageScaling   = FL_ENABLE;
        FL_PMU_Sleep_Init(PMU, &LPM_InitStruct);
}
```

I have also removed 8Mhz external oscillator:

[image: I have also removed 8Mhz external oscillator]

Comment: Welcome to the EE Stack Exchange. **(1)** You can contact the manufacturer for a datasheet in English. **(2)** I would have never used something for which a datasheet were not accessible but then you may have your reasons to do so. **(3)** Build a minimal example board and test several of these to verify that the problem persists. **(4)** Someone may still be able to help you, so please include your schematic **(5)** Include the deep sleep mode invocation code, if any)

Comment: Thank you Syed for the feedback. 
1. I have contacted and still waiting for the response. 2. The reasons are the chip shortage :). 3. I have removed almost all external modules from the circuit (including external HF oscillator). 4. The schematic and the code are included.

Comment: You need to read the errata. Sleep modes is one of the things that often tend to have silicon bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull-up resistors connected to JTAG header were too small. After removing them the current consumption became 1-2uA.